# How to do you insert a JSONArray as a Geometry in MySQL from Java?

Tags: java, mysql, types, casting, geojson

I am writing a JAVA program to populate a MySQL table with data (using JDBC). One of the columns has the type geometry.

I currently have a JSONArray holding the geometry data, but when I try to insert the data into the mysql I get the error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3971)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1552)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2607)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1480)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Mysql JSON Data Type
[click](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)